# javascript : simple delayed image show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to write a simple javascript snippet which delays the image loading by a certain number of millisecs below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


function SetTimer()
{
        var Timer = setInterval("showImage()",3000);
}

function showImage()
{
document.getElementById('showImage').style.visibility = 'visible';

}


</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="SetTimer()" style="visibility:hidden">
<div id=showImage>
<a href="home.php"><img src="gwyneth_paltrow_2.jpg"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically an OK approach.
There are some bugs, namely:

```
document.getElementByID('showImage')style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

`getElementByID` should be `getElementById`

needs a dot after ('showImage')

You are setting the visibility to 'hidden' in order to show it.  Instead, you should start out as hidden, and then make it appear instead of disappear.

Comment: you're right, its backwards.  I made the adjustments accordingly.

Comment: @phill - Still doesn't do what you said you wanted, the visibility state doesn't delay load the image, it just delays the display of it. That's not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('showImage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code is backwards given the stated goal of delaying the appearance of the image. If I just use your code as a basis, then I would have the visibility of the image as hidden, using CSS, and then trigger the display to visible on the timer.

However, having said that... This doesn't delay the loading of the image, it merely delays the display of it. The other way to handle it is to use the timer to load an Image object in Javascript and then insert it into the DOM. This, then, will actually delay the loading of the image for 3 seconds. Something like this:

```
function showImage()
{
  var myImage = new Image();
  myImage.src = "gwyneth_paltrow_2.jpg";
  document.getElementById("showImage").appendChild(myImage);
}
```

I'm doing that from memory, so syntax may not be entirely correct.